# Return updated document with Monger

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

In Monger there is a `insert-and-return` function for returning a newly inserted document.

There is no `update-and-return` function.

How can I return an updated document from the function that executes the update?

I think I could use `save-and-return` but it seems to me that I am not able to use operators like `$push` with this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two options for you.

First option is to use [JohnnyHK's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153119/return-updated-document-with-monger#14349338) with `find-and-modify` function:

```
(mc/find-and-modify "users"
  (select-keys my-doc [:_id])
  { $push { :awards { :award "IBM Fellow"
                      :year  1963
                      :by    "IBM" }}}
  :return-new true)
```

---

Second option is to use `save` instead of `update`. It's a good choice if you already have the entire document loaded from mongodb. You can easily replace mongodb operators like `$push` with `clojure` functions like [update-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/update-in). Manipulation with clojure maps seems for me as better approach. If you have problems with finding clojure alternatives for mongodb operators I can help you.

For my previous example it will look like this:

```
(mc/save-and-return "users"
  (update-in my-doc [:awards] conj
    { :award "IBM Fellow"
      :year  1963
      :by    "IBM" }))
```

Myself, I prefer this way, because it looks more Clojure-ish.

Answer (score 4):

This is the purpose of Monger's [`find-and-modify`](http://reference.clojuremongodb.info/monger.collection.html#var-find-and-modify) function.

```
;; Atomically find the doc with a language of "Python", set it to "Clojure", and
;; return the updated doc.
(mgcol/find-and-modify collection 
  {:language "Python"} 
  {:$set {:language "Clojure"} }
  :return-new true)
```

Comment: Thanks. I accepted Leonid's answer because he has the lower reputation and he will benefit more of the bounty. As I cannot accept both answers I at least upvoted yours. Hope that's ok for you.

Comment: @CodeBrickie I can't say I agree since Leonid basically copied my answer, but as Obiwan said: "You must do what you feel is right, of course."

Comment: He copied yours and added a second option. So he produced substantial value as well.